# Is it possible to achieve edge lighting notification in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, notifications, flutter-packages, flutter2.0

I am new to flutter and I want to achieve the functionality of lighting the mobile edge whenever I receive notification in my app.

Is there any package available? (Although, I already google it and I can't find it.)
How can we achieve this type of functionality?

Reference link of that kind of application:

[Edge Lighting Colors - Flash Alerts](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lightingcolor.border.edgeround.screen.free)


[Edge Lighting Colors - Round Colors Galaxy](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.edgeround.lightingcolors.rgb)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is anyone find it useful or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When there is no package available then you have to write one yourself.
Read about the native Android API and implement it in a [Flutter Plugin](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages#plugin).
You can also do it without a separate package by implementing it directly in the `MainActivity` and connecting it to Flutter via a [MethodChannel](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels#step-3-add-an-android-platform-specific-implementation).

Comment: So, without having knowledge of the native language we can't achieve this type of functionality?

Comment: No, this use case is too specific for Flutter to handle out of the box.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the reply! I wish some flutter package developer see my question and help me. LoL :)